# Is it possible to kill a MongoDB query using the Java Async Driver

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-java

This ticket makes it seem like it is possible to kill Java queries via session identifier. https://jira.mongodb.org/browse/JAVA-1109

Does anyone know the relevant API in order to achieve this?

Comment: https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/command/killSessions/

Comment: Thanks. Is it possible to do this via the Java driver?